# solaris.grant and granting/delegating rights?

Tags: permissions, solaris

I have a couple of question regarding Solaris 11...

First off, as far as I can tell, Solaris has dropped the auth solaris.grant in Solaris 11...  Why was it removed?  Is it no longer needed?  Did it get a new name?  Is there alternatives - eg. using several other auths to gain the same result?  Can it be reintroduced by editing a file like /etc/security/auths_attr (or what it's called, the file that lists auths)?

Second, how exactly *does* a user with the authority to grant or delegate rights (profiles, roles, auths) to other users?  Which commands are involved?  Can rights be granted both permanently and transiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.grant` authorization has [evolved](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/rights-1.html) in two finer grained ones, `.assign` which is unrestricted and `.delegate` with which you can only delegate profiles already assigned to you.